# Sapi keeps sending keystrokes to all of the (one) process windows

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am trying to send keystrokes to a custom main windows forms program using Sapi (in-proc, using VS2010 Express and C#).

The problem is that when Sapi recognizes a phrase, it does send the appropriate keys, but it sends them to ALL open windows of the process of that main program.

The issue here is that my Sapi program is like a plug-in to that other main program so it "lives" in it, so I am sending the keys through an exposed method for sending keys of that main program and *not* by the usual .net send.keys, so I don't have the option to deal with window handles.

on the other hand, when I have the same exact method to send the keys inside a button click event on a form and actually click the button with the mouse, the problem doesn't happen and the keys are sent only to the focused window as it should, and not the rest of the open windows as well.

I tried using the "speech_recognized" event to call a "perform_click()" on that button on the form every time there is a recognition and it does work and sends the keys, but again.. to all the windows of that process.

So I am pretty sure here that it's about "who makes the call" and that led me to the "object sender" that is at the recognized event:

void engine_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e) {…}

I think I might lack the knowledge about how to detach the Sapi "recognized" event from being the object that invokes the sending of the keys even though I tried to neutralize it and pass the call for my send keys method in many ways, it seems as it always knows it has been initially been called by Sapi and not by a method on the form or the button click event and behaves accordingly.

Another thing I tried for example is to assign the recognized phrase to the value of a global string and then called a void method on the form that accepts no parameters as well, and invoking the method for sending the keys with the value of that global string.

That too, though I don't understand how, knew it comes from Sapi and sent the keys to all open windows. Maybe a reference thing which I can't see and know nothing about? 
So because I think it's the "Object sender" that is keeping its reference and that is why it happens, I've tried casting "sender" as "Form" or "Button" or "Control" but it's not possible to cast this object to these, so I tried to make it null after I read the values from it and then send them to the one focused window of the main program But it seems the object keeps alive somehow (although all watches shows "Null") and keeps sending the keys to all open windows.

I've tried speechRecognitionEngine.RecognizeAsyncStop(); right after the recognition but it still is the sender object.

I also tried speechRecognitionEngine.Dispose(); right after getting the recognized result.

And also trying to null everything after the recognition: the engine, the "object sender", the "e" of the arguments. 
At the time after recognition, it doesn't suppose to have no effect on what happens next.
But it does..

I have tried everything I could think of- hours on hours of debugging.. 
Please help me out here.. 
what can I do to overcome this issue? 
Help is much appreciated!

Thank you.
Ray.

---

Update:

@EricBrown Thanks a lot Mr. Brown. I understand much better now.
you sure got me out of digging in the wrong place..

actually I am not trying to bypass any window or anything, 
I *do* need to send the keys to the focused window but my program sends it to all windows of that main program's process, focused or not.

in the contrary as I mentioned to clicking a button on my program that calls the exact same send keys method which only sends the keys to the focused window.

The thing is that the main program doesn't provide a way through its API to assign a handle of a window to its send keys method and also, I guess that because SAPI is at lower level, then it sends it to all of the windows in the process. and that is what I don't understand. the send keys code is fine if I click the button but if I call a method with that code or "perform_click" on that button by SAPI, it sends it to all windows, focused or not.

I will mention I've tried everything, including setting the focus to the active window before sending the keys to it, it just sends it to all windows.

now I am trying to find a way to send it only to the focused window by the main program API but it looks as it is not possible.. if you have any idea in mind of how could this be made/hacked I would love to hear..

much appreciated.. Thanks again!

---

another update:

```
    public void sendMyKeys(string stringToSend)
    {
        MainProgram.FocusMainWindow();
        MainProgram.SendKeystrokes(stringToSend);

    }

 sendMyKeys("Test");
```

Comment: This isn't SAPI related; this is a problem with your sendkeys code.  SendInput puts the items in the global keyboard queue, and gets sent to the application with focus.  Whatever you're doing to bypass this is causing the trouble.

Comment: So you need to show your code that's sending the keys.

Comment: @EricBrown Well.. there is nothing much to it, but I've added it.. Thanks!

Comment: If `MainProgram.SendKeystrokes()` isn't code you wrote, then you're out of luck.  The only *possible* option might be that you need to pump messages for around 2-300 ms to let the `MainProgram.FocusMainWindow()` call complete.  (This likely won't fix the issue, but it might be worth a try.)

Comment: Thanks again.. if you mean that I need to give some time in order for the MainProgram window to be focused then I can tell you it's totally focused, the thing is that I get the keys sent to it and to the other non-focused windows of that program as well. 
does your suggestion still apply? it's a single threaded program for what its worth (I am not knowledgeable in these matters) from what I read and tried to understand, there might be a window procedure that is shared between all windows of that program to handle messages and that is why they all get the keys?

Comment: and if so, what about if I'll try to use an Application.AddMessageFilter Method to block SAPI messages from windows that are not focused? that is if I'll know how to tell the messages are from SAPI and I'll manage to accomplish that.. am I way off? Thanks again!

Comment: Yes, you're way off.  1)  SAPI doesn't send any keys.  `MainProgram.SendKeystrokes` sends keys.    Whatever that does is causing the problems.

Comment: Thanks again Mr. Brown.. I was researching and testing.. so as you said, SAPI doesn't send any specific messages but I should be able to filter messages like WM_CHAR from any window of the main program only while it doesn't have focus right? if so, what do you think would be the best way to achieve this? Thanks again!